# How to call a method asynchronously in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous-method-call

I have a method `public void foo(){}` which in turn calls another method `public void fooBL(){}`
which is in the BusinessLogic layer. `fooBL()` then calls another method `fooDAL()` which is in the DataAccessLayer. I want to call `foo()` asynchronously on a button click event. I'm using .NET4.0.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I read about using task.run and using delegate.BeginInvoke(), but till now i'm not getting a clear idea on which one will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is.

The simplest way to call foo asynchronous is:

```
Task t = new Task.Factory.StartNew(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use thread to run method asynchronously. Below is an example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(foo));              
t.Start();
```

I hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap anything in `Task.Run` to run it via the default scheduler (the ThreadPool):

```
Task.Run(() => {
    yourMethodCallHere();
});
```

You should avoid the use of `StartNew` if you are unaware of how it works. You could introduce potential bugs as it captures the currently executing `TaskScheduler` instance and you will no doubt hit "cross-thread" exceptions when dealing with UI elements (or other, much more subtle bugs).

Comment: task.run is not available in .net 4.0